# Why does FlatBufferBuilder.dataBuffer return a different buffer than java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap?

Tags: java, flatbuffers

I am trying to send a float over the network from a program written in c# on windows to an android application written in java using flatbuffers.

From the received bytes in the android application a buffer is build using java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap. From this buffer the Example object is deserialized. This however results in every float being set to 0.

In the example below this behavior is shown.

Why does "example2" return the value `0.0` instead of `20.0`?

This is the schema i use:

```
// Example IDL file for our monster's schema.
namespace MyGame.Sample;
table Example {
  myFloat:float;
}
root_type Example;
```

This is the java code which show the behaviour:

```
//The float
float myFloat = 20.0f;

FlatBufferBuilder builder = new FlatBufferBuilder(0);

//Build the example
Example.startExample(builder);
Example.addMyFloat(builder, myFloat);
int exampleInt = Example.endExample(builder);

builder.finish(exampleInt);

java.nio.ByteBuffer buf = builder.dataBuffer();

Example example = Example.getRootAsExample(buf);

System.out.println("1: Myfloat: " + example.myFloat());

byte[] bytesBuf = buf.array();
Example example2 = Example.getRootAsExample(java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesBuf));

System.out.println("2: Myfloat: " + example2.myFloat());
```

Output:

```
System.out: 1: Myfloat: 20.0
System.out: 2: Myfloat: 0.0
```

Comment: What does the source for FlatBuffers suggest?

Comment: In the source of Flatbuffers it uses a java.nio.Bytebuffer with little endian order. Even if i change the buffer for example2 to little endian it still has the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array() gets the raw underlyimg buffer, which contains the FlatBuffer at an offset possibly other than 0. Instead, there's a method in FlatBufferBuilder (whose name escapes me right now) that will get you the buffer.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed the offset.